# MVC partial render

Tags: asp.net-mvc

if renderpartial in MVC is not like Update panel in ASP.net. than how does it works, and what about the efficiency. I heard that update panel was so inefficient in use. But how does MVC handles postbacks, I need to undestand this before I can dive into MVC

Any suggestions
thank you

Comment: MVC does not have "postbacks", you have to build and handle your own posts.

Comment: posts and gets are handled by action methods

Comment: So in webforms every server control you use has its state stored in something called view state. The framework will automatically post this back to the server and bind all of the variables up for you. In MVC it's more manual but still abstracted enough to enable quick development. You should read a book on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to update part of your page, the method I use is as follows:

- Link a JavaScript function to the event you want to use to update the 'panel'
- Make a jQuery AJAX call to an action in your controller
- from the controller return a call to the partial view
- this will cause the resulting HTML from the partial view to be returned as HTML to your AJAX call
- use jQuery to add the HTML to an existing empty div

The AJAX call looks something like

```
$.ajax({
    url: yourControllerAction URL,
    data: { CodeTypeID: codeTypeID }, // optional data
    type: "POST",
    success: function (returnedHtml) {
        $("#myDiv").html(htmreturnedHtmll);
    }
});
```

The rest is standard MVC

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

ASP.MVC Partial views are just reusable HTML fragments that can be populated by View Models. They don't have any special built in functionality like update panels do.

In general terms, with ASP.MVC **you** control post backs. In fact, you have to code it all yourself in HTML and JavaScript.

I suggest you [start here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials).